# Third-party DS4 keeps disconnecting - Linux bluetooth

Tags: linux, bluetooth, connection, gamepad

Well, I've already lost hours and hours trying to keep a connection of this gamepad. The name of the device is Q300 :
[Q300-PS4-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NFgU.png). You can find it by searching for "Q300 PS4".

Now, to the problem : it simply disconnects right after the connection, and there is almost no clue about it.

System : Debian trixie

`journalctl -xeu bluetooth` :

```
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: Starting SDP server
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support csip plugin
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: profiles/audio/micp.c:micp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support micp plugin
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support vcp plugin
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support mcp plugin
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bass plugin
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bap plugin
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: src/adapter.c:reset_adv_monitors_complete() Failed to reset Adv Monitors: Failed (0x03)
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: Battery Provider Manager created
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: Failed to clear UUIDs: Failed (0x03)
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
mar 16 18:03:05 desk bluetoothd[162449]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.303 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_hq
|| same for ldac_sq, ldac_sq, aptx_hd, aptx, sbc, sbc_xq_453, sbc_xq_512, sbc_xq_552
```

- From what I've read around, the SAP messages are just something that Debian should already got rid off some years ago. It is not something that should block anything related to it.
- I had to short the output because *superuser* thought that it was spam

And then from `bluetoothctl` :

```
[bluetooth]# hci0 A0:5A:5D:63:0C:47 type BR/EDR connected eir_len 26
[CHG] Device A0:5A:5D:63:0C:47 Connected: yes
[Q300]# hci0 A0:5A:5D:63:0C:47 type BR/EDR disconnected with reason 0
[CHG] Device A0:5A:5D:63:0C:47 Connected: no
```

Regarding the steps to pair & connect, I've used [this guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sony_DualShock#DualShock_4).

- once, after reading one of the hundred pages that I've tried, I added the `connect` command and it worked for like 30 mins. Then I was never able to reproduce this behavior anymore.

Regarding the  BT controller, it worked fine with DS3 gamepads so far.

Any help would be appreciated.